# how to include some php file to another folder using include

Tags: php

I am using include or include_once  in php core project

`include('test1/footer.php');` this is working in root folder ..

but we using above code in anyfolder like name test2 and include test1 file in test2 here above code not working..`include('test1/footer.php');`

please help me .

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**folder structure**

```
/root
    /test1
        footer.php
    index.php
```

**index.php**

```
//works fine because test1 is on the same level as index.php
include('test1/footer.php');
```

---

**folder structure**

```
/root
    /test1
        footer.php
    /test2
        index.php
```

**index.php**

```
//does not work since in our current folder there is no folder "test1"
include('test1/footer.php');
//does work since we go back to root first
include('../test1/footer.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`include('../test1/footer.php');`

But both test1 and test2 on same level.

Answer (score 0):

http://prntscr.com/8ho3gk

check this screen shot to understand structure

if you want to add "configs.php" in "cargo.php"
write this include('include/configs.php');
and
if you want to add "cargo.php" in "configs.php"
write this include('../cargo.php');

better use include_once(); not only include();

Answer (score 0):

best practice for me is to define a constant containing server ROOT path 
(or other path that is base for your includes)

add code to 
`root/index.php` or to a configuration file if you have one

```
define('MYROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

use it anywhere in the project code, its also good when you change files hierarchy:

```
include(MYROOT.'test1/footer.php');
```